# How to convert an integer value to string value

Tags: java

```
 orderAttributeType.setName(hirTask.getEscalationLevel());
```

HI,
    here i am getting integer value to  by using these(hirTask.getEscalationLevel).setname is expexcting sting value.Can any one tell me how to parse integer to string.

Comment: `Integer.toString(int value)`

Comment: search on **Google** first.

Comment: have you tried `String.valueOf(myInteger)`?

Comment: `String.valueOf(intVariable);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Integer.toString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) like

```
Integer.toString(hirTask.getEscalationLevel())
```

or [`String.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29)

```
String.valueOf(hirTask.getEscalationLevel())
```

or even

```
"" + hirTask.getEscalationLevel()
```

Comment: I don't think that `"" + int` is a good way to do that:)

Comment: @pbespechnyi That **is** why it's last on the list!

Answer (score 2):

Try `String.valueOf(int)` or if integer in a wrapper class object `integer.toString()`.

Comment: `Integer` not `integer` :)

Comment: @TheLostMind, `Integer` is a class, `integer` is an object;)

Comment: `public static String toString(int i)` :)

Comment: @TheLostMind, ahaha, yes, there is a static method:)